# Abstract Class: Single Constructor, access modifier?

Tags: c#, class, constructor, abstract

I have the following code snippet:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected Foo()
}
```

Is there any difference in inheritance between using protected as the access modifier or public?

I´ve mostly seen using protected in this case.
So there is the difference and why do people use proteced over public?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There *may* be some subtle situations where it would make a difference (and it would be *detectable* with reflection) but essentially they're the same. It's probably *clearer* to make it `protected`, as it can't actually be called other than by a constructor of a derived class.

Answer (score 2):

One difference is if you plan on serializing the class, then you must have a default `public` constructor (default meaning the constructor takes no arguments). Otherwise, like Jon says the difference is slight.

Comment: This plays a role in the application i´m writing, from which my question rose. Interesting point thank you!